# When I click the increase button, the number labeled below it must be increased in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

- I would like to increment the number in `Tkinter Label` by 1 when a
  `Tkinter Button` is pressed.

This is the code I implemented so far but doesn't work:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.f = Frame(root, height = 1000, width = 350)
        self.f.pack()
        self.b = Button(self.f,text = 'Increase',height = 2, width = 15, command = self.buttonClick(1))
        self.b.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        self.b.pack()

    def buttonClick(self, num):
        b = 1
        
        if num == 1:
            a = Label(text = str(b))
            a.pack()
            
root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x1000')

mb = Game(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
You show no output, and you specify no problem.

Comment: Post the output of this code and the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Few things were wrong in your code that needed correction:

1. You can't use two different layout managers (you are using `grid` and also `pack` and that is not allowed unfortunately).
2. Every time you call the method `command = self.buttonClick(1)` you pass the same argument `1`. You don't increase anything. Also you should use `lambda` functions here: `command = lambda: self.buttonClick(1)`. Because in your approach you pass the the `command` parameter what `self.buttonClick(1)` returns (your `buttonClick` method won't even execute!).
3. But still there is easier approach with using `IntVar` object.

The whole working code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.f = Frame(root, height = 1000, width = 350)
        self.f.pack()

        self.number = IntVar(0)

        self.a = Label(self.f, textvariable = self.number)
        self.a.pack()

        self.b = Button(self.f, text = 'Increase', height = 2, width = 15, command = self.buttonClick)
        self.b.pack()

        

    def buttonClick(self):
        self.number.set(self.number.get() + 1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x1000')

mb = Game(root)

root.mainloop()
```